# Retrieve data from Weather.asmx goes in error path-Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services

I want to retrieve some data from Weather.asmx and wrote below code to get some data. There was no error from Javascript as I have seen but when the program runs it always go to groupPropertiesErrorHandler function. Any idea?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#butCallAjax').click(function() {
            jQuery.support.cors = true;
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx/GetCityWeatherByZIP?ZIP=10007",
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
                },
                success: groupPropertiesSuccessHandler,
                error: groupPropertiesErrorHandler
            });
        });

        function groupPropertiesSuccessHandler(data) {
            var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
            var properties = 'Group Properties:\n';
            alert(properties);
        }

        // Error Handler
        function groupPropertiesErrorHandler(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
            alert("Could not get the group properties: " + errorMessage);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is this a cross domain request? If so, you may be being blocked by the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: Is there anyway to overcome cross domain request from client side?

Comment: If the 3rd party supports it, you can use JSONP or CORS. If they don't, then no, you would have to use a server side proxy.

Comment: Thanks. Got your point.